# Двойной запрос

Tags: sql

Есть такая задача: найти строки, где 2 переменные >0, затем в тех, что нашел, найти те строки, где соотношение этих переменных < 0.96. Поясню в коде, который у меня не работает -

```
select * from  table1
where (coalesce(perem1,0)>0 and coalesce(perem2,0)>0) /*находим ненулевые строки*/
and (:proc>=perem2/perem1*100) /*найти из тех строк процент от числа меньший :proc/*
```

Можно как-то сначала выбрать строки, где переменные больше нуля, а затем из того, что нашел, выбрать строки, где процент `perem2` меньше `:proc` был, в два запроса или еще как-то?

Comment: Что-то мне сдается, что если взять переменную больше нуля, но меньше 0,96, то это всего-то один запрос. т.е.   
  
    переменная >0 and переменная <0.96

Comment: Не так сначала делает 1 запрос найти строки где perem1 и perem2 >0 , затем в тех строках что нашел найти например perem2/perem1*100 < 0.96
Вот то есть два запроса или еще как то не знаю. как это сделать?

Comment: perem1 > 0 and perem2 > 0 and perem2/perem1*100 < 0.96 

что, так нельзя????

Comment: Нет, так как `perem1` и `perem2` могут = 0, а делить на нуль нельзя, поэтому и нужно 2 запроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут нет смысла использовать coalesce, вам же нужно только одну переменную преобразовать из null. ISNULL проще

```
select * from  table1 
where (isnull(perem1,0)>0 and isnull(perem2,0)>0) /*находим ненулевые строки*/ 
and (:proc>=perem2/perem1*100) /*найти из тех строк процент от числа меньший :proc/*
```

на MS SQL такой запрос работает, потому что (isnull(perem1,0)>0 and isnull(perem2,0)>0) проверяется раньше
Если строго подходить, то можно так:

```
select * from  table1 
where (coalesce(perem1,0)>0 and coalesce(perem2,0)>0) /*находим ненулевые строки*/ 
and (:proc>=perem2/(case when perem1 is null or perem1 = 0 then 1 else perem1 end)*100) /*найти из тех строк процент от числа меньший :proc/*
```

Comment: Я же сказал проблема в том что perem1 и perem2 иногда бываеют равно 0, а на нуль делить нельзя. поэтому и нужно сначала отобрать строки где perem1 и perem2 > 0

Comment: добавил в ответ разъяснений. проверено на MS SQL - уловие сначала проверяет первую скобку и, если она ложна - вторую не считает

Comment: Делаю на FireBird пишит unknow columns perem1

Comment: Может как то можно вложеным запросом сделать это? хотя как ему делать?

Comment: на каком запросе - первом или втором? не работал с firebird. ну если так хочется с подзапросом - то так

    select * from 
    (select * from  table1  
    where (isnull(perem1,0)>0 and isnull(perem2,0)>0))
    Q
    where  
(:proc>=perem2/perem1*100)

Comment: Попробуйте еще такой вариант

   select * from table1 
   where (coalesce(perem1,0)>0 and coalesce(perem2,0)>0)     
   and (0.96>=perem2/perem1*100.) 

т.е. после 100 поставьте точку

Comment: Ни первое ни второе ни помогло. При первом жалуется на вторую Select, во втором случае все пишит - арифметическая ошибка или деление на нуль.

Comment: видимо это связано с порядком вычисления выражений на разных серверах. в firebird скорее всего нет isnull, но case то есть. работает второй запрос из ответа?

    select * from @t1
    where (coalesce(perem1,0)>0 and coalesce(perem2,0)>0) 
   and (0.96>=perem2/(case when perem1 is null or perem1 = 0 then 1 else perem1 end)*100)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте функцию :

```
IIf(«expression»; «truepart»; «falsepart»)
```

Функция `IIf` делает выражение `«expression»` и если результат "правда", выполняется первое, иначе второе.
Ну, не скажу что красиво но попробуйте так:

```
IIf(perem1 > 0; perem2/perem1*100 < 0.96; 0 > 1);
или
IIf(perem1 > 0; perem2/perem1*100 < 0.96; false); - не уверен
```

Comment: его можно прямо в запросе where писать? а альтернатива есть?

Comment: Да конечно! Прямо в запросе `Where`. Вместо  

    perem2/perem1*100 < 0.96

Comment: Эта функция возвращает результат выполнения одного из двух операторов. Т.к. нам нельзя делить на ноль, то ф-я делает проверку, и если она "ложь", то не будет исполняться первый оператор, где будет получаться деление на ноль

Comment: А в качестве альтернативы я вижу только хранимую процедуру или функцию.